# Why does Watir-webdriver open two browsers?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir-webdriver

I'm working on website test automation using Cucumber/Ruby/Selenium-Webdriver/Capybara. I want to switch to Watir-Webdriver in combination with Cucumber and Ruby, but I'm struggling with the following:

Every time I run my cucumber test, Watir opens two browser windows, a blank screen to the site I configurated as default, plus another in which the actual test steps are executed.

My 'Support/env.rb' file has:

```
require 'allure-cucumber'
require 'rspec'
require 'watir-webdriver'

AllureCucumber.configure do |c|
  c.output_dir = 'D:\Test\result'
  c.clean_dir  = true
  c.tms_prefix      = '@PRACTEST--'
  c.issue_prefix    = '@JIRA++'
  c.severity_prefix = '@URGENCY:'
  c.tms_prefix =  ''
end
```

My steps file begins with:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'cucumber'
require 'rspec'
require_relative 'D:\EntelTest\src\PageObject\home_page.rb'

Before  do
  @test = AbstractPage.new(Watir::Browser.new :ff)
  @test.full_size
end

After  do
  @test.quit
end


home_page = nil


When(/^Go to home page$/) do
  home_page  = @test.goToHomePage

end
```

Comment: Not likely related to your issue, but Watir-Webdriver is deprecated. It has been replaced by Watir v6.0 or greater.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages. SO isn't a discussion list, it's a reference site, like a cookbook or encyclopedia. As such concise questions are preferred over verbose ones; A little personality is great but remember, you're creating a new entry in the book to help others, not writing in a message thread so keep it to the point. Also, salutations, valedictions and signatures are not desirable.

Comment: Can you put these `before do` and `after do` in hooks.rb? In the steps.rb file, just mention the code for your cucumber steps, and before that declare 

`browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff`

Comment: @MrityunjeyanS    thanks that is help fo my case.But i put not in hooks.rb i put it on env.rb

Comment: @DmitriyAndrienko : Cool! on a side note the best practice is to put it in `hooks.rb`. `env.rb` usually should consist the desired capabilities plus server environment codes. :)

I have updated the answer. Please accept  the answer, if it had helped you in resolving your bug :) 

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you put these before do and after do in `hooks.rb`? In the `steps.rb` file, just mention the code for your cucumber steps, and before that declare `browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff`

The best practice is to put it in hooks.rb. env.rb usually should consist the desired capabilities plus server environment codes. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you have put in step file should go in hooks.rb file.

Please install gem called testnow. 
It will help you to create most standard and easy to use watir-webdriver framework with all pre-configured browsers.

Steps:

```
1) gem install testnow   
2) testnow watir_cucumber_now
```

It will as you to install dependecies, enter Y to set it up completely.
It will create robust framework with a sample scenario.

Just run the sample scenario with any of the following commands.

```
rake testnow BROWSER=firefox
rake testnow BROWSER=chrome
rake testnow BROWSER=opera
```

This will only work provided you have browsers pre-installed and webdriver present in PATH variable.

Please comment for more information.

Hope it helps!!